# document.querySelector is returning null for a very simple beginner problem. I have no idea why

Tags: javascript, queryselector

html is basically boiler plate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="text-input" required placeholder="Please input a value" />
    <button id="check-btn"></button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
const textInput = document.querySelector("input");

console.log(textInput);
```

returns null. Ive watched youtube videos and do exactly what they did and console will log the input element. Ive also tried using .text-input and #text-input

Comment: change `<script src="script.js"></script>` to `<script src="script.js" defer></script>`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use script tag after body tag ( you're using it in head tag ). Now lets come to solution so you're using wrong command. Try this javascript code instead:

const textInput = document.querySelector("text-input").innerHTML;
console.log(textInput);

I hope this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: `after body tag` no, preferably INSIDE the body tag, right at the bottom - if you want to write "correct" HTML :p

Comment: Thanks for the correction, will implement this from now onwards.

Comment: It's not that it "won't work" of course, browsers are fairly forgiving. Best to write semantically correct HTML though

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, your script runs before the complete DOM renders. so that your `queryselector` didn't able to get input element.

To Resolve It Just add `defer` in your script tag.

It will executed after the page has finished parsing.

Solution code :

```js
const textInput = document.querySelector("input");

console.log(textInput);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="text-input" required placeholder="Please input a value" />
    <button id="check-btn"></button>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
```

Thank You